# AUC curve didn't even show on the plot

Tags: python, machine-learning, auc

After using logistic regression to predict stuff, this is the confusion matrix I got:

```
True Positives: 3
False Positives: 1309
True Negatives: 12361
False Negatives: 4
```

The roc_auc_score is here:

```
roc_auc_score(y_test, log_preds)
0.6664071480823492
```

So I want to visualize it using this chunk of code:

```
probas = lg.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
def get_preds(threshold, probabilities):
    return [1 if prob > threshold else 0 for prob in probabilities]
roc_values = []
for thresh in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):
    preds = get_preds(thresh, probas)
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, log_preds).ravel()
    tpr = tp/(tp+fn)
    fpr = fp/(fp+tn)
    roc_values.append([tpr, fpr])
tpr_values, fpr_values = zip(*roc_values)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
ax.plot(fpr_values, tpr_values)
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, 100),
         np.linspace(0, 1, 100),
         label='baseline',
         linestyle='--')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic Curve', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('TPR', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('FPR', fontsize=16)
plt.legend(fontsize=12);
```

Below is the output, which only has one baseline, I don't understand.
(My reputation still not enough to embed an image, please feel free to edit it. Thanks!)

[This is the output of ROAUC plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m6QW.png)

Comment: am I reading it right that the dataset of ~15K samples has only 7 positives?

Comment: @Marat Yes, it is extremely unbalanced.

Comment: any metrics on such a dataset would not make a lot of sense then

Comment: @Marat isn't it that roc_auc score describes specifically the unbalanced data better? Or is there still limit for that

Comment: not at this level of imbalance

Comment: @Marat Is that the reason why the plot is not showing? Because it's too unbalanced?

Comment: no, it's a separate issue

Comment: @Marat I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I kinda figured out what's going on.

I wrote down this line of code to see what happened:

```
print(tpr_values)
print(fpr_values)
```

The out put:

```
(0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855)
(0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006, 0.09575713240673006)
```

All of the values are the same. So they all concentrate on the same points.

I solved my own problem. The output is normal now:

[image: The image I got]

The bug was here:

```
roc_values = []
for thresh in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):
    preds = get_preds(thresh, probas)
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, log_preds).ravel()
    tpr = tp/(tp+fn)
    fpr = fp/(fp+tn)
    roc_values.append([tpr, fpr])
tpr_values, fpr_values = zip(*roc_values)
```

After I fixed the `log_preds` , it looks like this:

```
roc_values = []
for thresh in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):
    preds = get_preds(thresh, probas)       #~~~~~~~~
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, preds).ravel()
    tpr = tp/(tp+fn)                        #^^^^^^^^
    fpr = fp/(fp+tn)
    roc_values.append([tpr, fpr])
tpr_values, fpr_values = zip(*roc_values)
```

It's quite frustrating, but whatever, it finally worked.